# Is UserInterfaceOnly=True setting now Saved with the workbook? (Worksheet.Protect Method)

Tags: excel, vba

It was known that UserInterfaceOnly:=True setting was not saved with the workbook. So every time a Wb was opened, the Worksheet.Protect method had to be used with UserInterfaceOnly set to True in order to enable vba to write to the protected cells without raising an error.

Now, in the office vba language reference for Excel dated 01/22/2022, Microsoft states that **in Previous Versions** the UserInterfaceOnly was not saved, thus giving the idea that (finally) in latest versions this setting should now be saved with the workbook (See image below).

[image: MS Excel vba language Ref]

If this is the case, then there should be no need to set it again every time the Wb is Opened.

Does anyone know what Microsoft means by **Previous Versions**?
And is this setting is now saved, this new behavior is starting on what version?

Comment: It would help if you provided a link to the page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect   The "Previous versions" URL contains "visual-studio-2010" so that would seem pretty old these days.

Comment: Thanks Tim for posting the link to the MS Page.

Comment: Just tested on a PC with Office 365 latest current channel release, and the UserInterfaceOnly is not saved. So the behaviour seem the same a it was.